# VS Code - Markdown Drag and Drop creating superfluous path

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, drag-and-drop, markdown, png

Now that VS Code supports drag and drop of images into Markdown (as of [v1.67](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_67.md#markdown-drop-into-editor-to-create-link), April 2022), I am having an issue with the path that it inserts. Instead of a relative path, I get a convoluted mixture of relative and absolute:

`![Alt Text](../../../../../../../C:/Users/kscharnhorst/Documents/)`

[image: Path created, then truncated to relative and still working]

In the above GIF I truncate the path to relative to show it still works, then I add an character to make the path invalid and show that the preview breaks. I delete the offending character and the preview once again shows the image.

In all the places I see the drag and drop functionality demonstrated by Microsoft I do not see this behavior. This does not happen in JavaScript, just Markdown. All extensions are disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you still reproduce this issue?

Comment: Nope, issue was resolved [at this commit](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/167862/commits/7f09e69406849e67b4c425a0f34ab22c6c5fd20d). I believe it made it into that January '23 release (v 1.75)

Comment: nice find. write that up as an answer post!